# ggsave() as svg fontconfig error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `ggsave()` for a ggplot to save as an svg.  When I do so, I get a fontconfig error.  I have installed and updated both `svglite` and `gdtools` packages.

I'm on MacOS Sierra.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + geom_boxplot() %>% 
ggsave(filename = "diamonds.svg")

Saving 11.6 x 5.32 in image
Error in match_family_(font, bold, italic) : 
  Fontconfig error: unable to match font pattern
```

Comment: what is the output of `gdtools::sys_fonts()`?

Comment: Empty! Returns a 0 row df.

Comment: OK, looks like an known issue with cairo and mac os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you:

1. Install/reinstall homebrew
2. run in command line: `brew install cairo`
3. In R `install.packages("gdtools")`

Comment: That did the trick.  I cleaned and pruned homebrew (already had it installed), then uninstalled cairo, reinstalled cairo, and deleted/reinstalled gdtools.  It now lists all my system fonts and ggsave works perfectly for svg.  Thank you!